# initialize mxgraph with default xml model

Tags: javascript, php, mxgraph

How can I start with an existing XML model in **mxgraph**.
I have a **default** XML graph and i want to import it on **mxgraph** load (start)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using the GraphEditor - Template**
You can set a default `mxGraphModel` by appling it with `setGraphXML`.
The following example shows you how to apply a default mxGraphModel.

In the `data`-object, declare your default model as xml. Then you can parse the model with `parseXml` to xml and then apply it to the graph.

[Implementation of setGraphXML in the GraphEditor](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/blob/e407026f5db3d40d3e39b3396dbed1b03e6f9608/javascript/examples/grapheditor/www/js/Editor.js#L469)

```
var data =
    '<mxGraphModel pageWidth="1169" pageHeight="827" background="#ffffff">' +
    '    <root>' +
    '        <mxCell id="0" />' +
    '        <mxCell id="1" parent="0" />' +
    '    </root>' +
    '</mxGraphModel>';
graph.model.beginUpdate();
try {
    var xml = mxUtils.parseXml(data).documentElement;
    setGraphXml(xml);
}
catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
finally {
    graph.model.endUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks Okeano,
I put it in index file and i got this javascript error " this.editorUi is undefined "

Comment: Hi, I updated the code in my answer(removed the linking to the editorUi and editor). To get this code working in your case, you have to implement the function [setGraphXML](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/blob/e407026f5db3d40d3e39b3396dbed1b03e6f9608/javascript/examples/grapheditor/www/js/Editor.js#L469) into your index-file.

Comment: Hello,
I got "this graph is not defined"
You can find my index file in this link
https://tatbikat.ma/index.txt

Comment: `graph` is the mxGraph-Object. You have to replace this to your mxGraph-Object variable.

Comment: I don't have an mxGraph-Object in my index.php 
can tou take a look to my code in https://tatbikat.ma/index.txt

Comment: Ok i found the solution of my problem 
i create a new editorUI
Thank you Okeano