# Using mxgraph to Construct and Render a Graph from an Existing XML String

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, reactjs, mxgraph

I'm attempting to use mxgraph to render a graph inside of a React component (similar to [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/eyupcolak/mxgraph_react_exercise1/tree/master/?from-embed) example someone created using the [mxgraph-js](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph-js) fork). I'd like this graph to be constructed using an existing XML string which was created earlier via the mxgraph [grapheditor](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/grapheditor/www/index.html) tool.

My React component looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import * as mxgraph from 'mxgraph';

const { mxClient, mxGraph, mxRubberband, mxUtils, mxEvent, mxKeyHandler, mxCodec } = mxgraph();

class DisplayGraph extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.LoadGraph = this.LoadGraph.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.LoadGraph();
  }

  LoadGraph() {
    var container = document.getElementById("divGraph");

    // Checks if the browser is supported
    if (!mxClient.isBrowserSupported()) {
      // Displays an error message if the browser is not supported.
      mxUtils.error("Browser is not supported!", 200, false);
    } else {
      // Disables the built-in context menu
      mxEvent.disableContextMenu(container);

      // Creates the graph inside the given container
      var graph = new mxGraph(container);

      // Gets the default parent for inserting new cells. This is normally the first child of the root (ie. layer 0).
      var parent = graph.getDefaultParent();

      // Enables tooltips, new connections and panning
      graph.setPanning(true);
      graph.setTooltips(true);
      graph.setConnectable(true);
      graph.setEnabled(true);
      graph.setEdgeLabelsMovable(false);
      graph.setVertexLabelsMovable(false);
      graph.setGridEnabled(true);
      graph.setAllowDanglingEdges(false);

      graph.getModel().beginUpdate();

      //construct graph from XML string
      try{
        console.log('Updating the graph');
        //In reality, this string will be fetched from a database. For now, we will use an example string
        let xmlString = '<mxGraphModel dx="116" dy="608" grid="1" gridSize="10" guides="1" tooltips="1" connect="1" arrows="1" fold="1" page="1" pageScale="1" pageWidth="850" pageHeight="1100"><root><mxCell id="0"/><mxCell id="1" parent="0"/><mxCell id="2" value="Template" style="rounded=1;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;strokeColor=#00ACC1;strokeWidth=5;glass=0;comic=0;gradientColor=#b2ebf2;fillColor=#e0f7fa;fontSize=16;fontColor=#000000;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="210" y="120" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="3" value="Sub-Process" style="shape=process;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;backgroundOutline=1;strokeColor=#ffb74d;strokeWidth=4;perimeterSpacing=0;fontSize=16;gradientColor=#fff3e0;fillColor=#FFFFFF;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="210" y="260" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="4" value="End" style="ellipse;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;aspect=fixed;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fillColor=#ffebee;strokeColor=#f44336;strokeWidth=4;gradientColor=#ffcdd2;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="240" y="400" width="80" height="80" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="5" value="Process" style="shape=process;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;backgroundOutline=1;strokeColor=#ff9800;strokeWidth=4;perimeterSpacing=0;fontSize=16;gradientColor=#ffe0b2;fillColor=#fff3e0;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="240" y="500" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="6" value="Start" style="ellipse;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;aspect=fixed;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fillColor=#e8f5e9;strokeColor=#4caf50;strokeWidth=4;gradientColor=#c8e6c9;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="270" y="640" width="80" height="80" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="7" value="Start" style="ellipse;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;aspect=fixed;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fillColor=#e8f5e9;strokeColor=#4caf50;strokeWidth=4;gradientColor=#c8e6c9;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="270" y="740" width="80" height="80" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="8" value="Documentation" style="shape=document;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;boundedLbl=1;strokeWidth=4;strokeColor=#9C27B0;gradientColor=#E1BEE7;fillColor=#F3E5F5;fontSize=16;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="270" y="840" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="9" value="Sub-Process" style="shape=process;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;backgroundOutline=1;strokeColor=#ffb74d;strokeWidth=4;perimeterSpacing=0;fontSize=16;gradientColor=#fff3e0;fillColor=#FFFFFF;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="300" y="980" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="10" value="Template" style="rounded=1;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;strokeColor=#00ACC1;strokeWidth=5;glass=0;comic=0;gradientColor=#b2ebf2;fillColor=#e0f7fa;fontSize=16;fontColor=#000000;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="330" y="1120" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="11" value="Decision" style="rhombus;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;rounded=0;glass=0;comic=0;labelBackgroundColor=none;strokeColor=#333333;strokeWidth=4;fillColor=#eeeeee;gradientColor=#e5e5e5;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fontColor=#000000;align=center;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="360" y="1260" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="12" value="End" style="ellipse;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;aspect=fixed;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fillColor=#ffebee;strokeColor=#f44336;strokeWidth=4;gradientColor=#ffcdd2;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="390" y="1400" width="80" height="80" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="13" value="Process" style="shape=process;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;backgroundOutline=1;strokeColor=#ff9800;strokeWidth=4;perimeterSpacing=0;fontSize=16;gradientColor=#ffe0b2;fillColor=#fff3e0;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="390" y="1500" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="14" value="Documentation" style="shape=document;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;boundedLbl=1;strokeWidth=4;strokeColor=#9C27B0;gradientColor=#E1BEE7;fillColor=#F3E5F5;fontSize=16;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="420" y="1640" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="15" value="Phase" style="swimlane;html=1;horizontal=0;swimlaneLine=0;rounded=0;glass=0;comic=0;labelBackgroundColor=none;strokeColor=#000000;strokeWidth=4;fillColor=#26C6DA;gradientColor=#00ACC1;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fontColor=#FFFFFF;gradientDirection=east;spacing=0;spacingTop=-4;swimlaneFillColor=none;collapsible=0;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="450" y="1780" width="1020" height="200" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="16" value="Phase" style="swimlane;html=1;horizontal=0;swimlaneLine=0;rounded=0;glass=0;comic=0;labelBackgroundColor=none;strokeColor=#000000;strokeWidth=4;fillColor=#26C6DA;gradientColor=#00ACC1;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fontColor=#FFFFFF;gradientDirection=east;spacing=0;spacingTop=-4;swimlaneFillColor=none;collapsible=0;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="480" y="2000" width="1020" height="200" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="17" value="Phase" style="swimlane;html=1;horizontal=0;swimlaneLine=0;rounded=0;glass=0;comic=0;labelBackgroundColor=none;strokeColor=#000000;strokeWidth=4;fillColor=#26C6DA;gradientColor=#00ACC1;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fontColor=#FFFFFF;gradientDirection=east;spacing=0;spacingTop=-4;swimlaneFillColor=none;collapsible=0;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="510" y="2220" width="1020" height="200" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="18" value="Phase" style="swimlane;html=1;horizontal=0;swimlaneLine=0;rounded=0;glass=0;comic=0;labelBackgroundColor=none;strokeColor=#000000;strokeWidth=4;fillColor=#26C6DA;gradientColor=#00ACC1;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fontColor=#FFFFFF;gradientDirection=east;spacing=0;spacingTop=-4;swimlaneFillColor=none;collapsible=0;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="540" y="2440" width="1020" height="200" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="19" value="Process" style="shape=process;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;backgroundOutline=1;strokeColor=#ff9800;strokeWidth=4;perimeterSpacing=0;fontSize=16;gradientColor=#ffe0b2;fillColor=#fff3e0;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="570" y="2660" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="20" value="Start" style="ellipse;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;aspect=fixed;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fillColor=#e8f5e9;strokeColor=#4caf50;strokeWidth=4;gradientColor=#c8e6c9;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="600" y="2800" width="80" height="80" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="21" value="Process" style="shape=process;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;backgroundOutline=1;strokeColor=#ff9800;strokeWidth=4;perimeterSpacing=0;fontSize=16;gradientColor=#ffe0b2;fillColor=#fff3e0;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="600" y="2900" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="22" value="Action" style="rounded=1;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;glass=0;comic=0;labelBackgroundColor=none;strokeColor=#e91e63;strokeWidth=4;fillColor=#fce4ec;gradientColor=#f8bbd0;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fontColor=#000000;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="630" y="3040" width="280" height="40" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="23" value="Process" style="shape=process;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;backgroundOutline=1;strokeColor=#ff9800;strokeWidth=4;perimeterSpacing=0;fontSize=16;gradientColor=#ffe0b2;fillColor=#fff3e0;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="660" y="3100" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="24" value="Sub-Process" style="shape=process;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;backgroundOutline=1;strokeColor=#ffb74d;strokeWidth=4;perimeterSpacing=0;fontSize=16;gradientColor=#fff3e0;fillColor=#FFFFFF;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="690" y="3240" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="25" value="End" style="ellipse;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;aspect=fixed;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fillColor=#ffebee;strokeColor=#f44336;strokeWidth=4;gradientColor=#ffcdd2;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="720" y="3380" width="80" height="80" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="26" value="Decision" style="rhombus;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;rounded=0;glass=0;comic=0;labelBackgroundColor=none;strokeColor=#333333;strokeWidth=4;fillColor=#eeeeee;gradientColor=#e5e5e5;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fontColor=#000000;align=center;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="720" y="3480" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="27" value="Template" style="rounded=1;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;strokeColor=#00ACC1;strokeWidth=5;glass=0;comic=0;gradientColor=#b2ebf2;fillColor=#e0f7fa;fontSize=16;fontColor=#000000;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="750" y="3620" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="28" value="Process" style="shape=process;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;backgroundOutline=1;strokeColor=#ff9800;strokeWidth=4;perimeterSpacing=0;fontSize=16;gradientColor=#ffe0b2;fillColor=#fff3e0;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="780" y="3760" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="29" value="Start" style="ellipse;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;aspect=fixed;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fillColor=#e8f5e9;strokeColor=#4caf50;strokeWidth=4;gradientColor=#c8e6c9;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="810" y="3900" width="80" height="80" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="30" value="Documentation" style="shape=document;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;boundedLbl=1;strokeWidth=4;strokeColor=#9C27B0;gradientColor=#E1BEE7;fillColor=#F3E5F5;fontSize=16;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="810" y="4000" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="31" value="Phase" style="swimlane;html=1;horizontal=0;swimlaneLine=0;rounded=0;glass=0;comic=0;labelBackgroundColor=none;strokeColor=#000000;strokeWidth=4;fillColor=#26C6DA;gradientColor=#00ACC1;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fontColor=#FFFFFF;gradientDirection=east;spacing=0;spacingTop=-4;swimlaneFillColor=none;collapsible=0;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="840" y="4140" width="1020" height="200" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="32" value="Action" style="rounded=1;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;glass=0;comic=0;labelBackgroundColor=none;strokeColor=#e91e63;strokeWidth=4;fillColor=#fce4ec;gradientColor=#f8bbd0;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fontColor=#000000;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="870" y="4360" width="280" height="40" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="33" value="Documentation" style="shape=document;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;boundedLbl=1;strokeWidth=4;strokeColor=#9C27B0;gradientColor=#E1BEE7;fillColor=#F3E5F5;fontSize=16;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="900" y="4420" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="34" value="Phase" style="swimlane;html=1;horizontal=0;swimlaneLine=0;rounded=0;glass=0;comic=0;labelBackgroundColor=none;strokeColor=#000000;strokeWidth=4;fillColor=#26C6DA;gradientColor=#00ACC1;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fontColor=#FFFFFF;gradientDirection=east;spacing=0;spacingTop=-4;swimlaneFillColor=none;collapsible=0;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="930" y="4560" width="1020" height="200" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="35" value="Process" style="shape=process;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;backgroundOutline=1;strokeColor=#ff9800;strokeWidth=4;perimeterSpacing=0;fontSize=16;gradientColor=#ffe0b2;fillColor=#fff3e0;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="960" y="4780" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="36" value="Sub-Process" style="shape=process;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;backgroundOutline=1;strokeColor=#ffb74d;strokeWidth=4;perimeterSpacing=0;fontSize=16;gradientColor=#fff3e0;fillColor=#FFFFFF;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="990" y="4920" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="37" value="Process" style="shape=process;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;backgroundOutline=1;strokeColor=#ff9800;strokeWidth=4;perimeterSpacing=0;fontSize=16;gradientColor=#ffe0b2;fillColor=#fff3e0;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="1020" y="5060" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell></root></mxGraphModel>';
        var doc = mxUtils.parseXml(xmlString);
        var codec = new mxCodec(doc);
        codec.decode(doc.documentElement, graph.getModel());
        graph.fit();
      }catch(error){
        console.log('An exception occurred while updating the graph:');
        console.log(error);
      }finally{
        graph.getModel().endUpdate();
        console.log('Graph updating ended');
      }

      // Enables rubberband (marquee) selection and a handler for basic keystrokes
      var rubberband = new mxRubberband(graph);
      var keyHandler = new mxKeyHandler(graph);
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log('DisplayGraph Rendered!');
    return (
        <div className="graph-container" ref="divGraph" id="divGraph" style={{height: "calc(100vh-120px)", width: "100%"}}></div>
    );
  }
}

export default DisplayGraph;
```

When this React component (DisplayGraph) is constructed and rendered in my React application, the graph never appears. Although it does appear to be initializing the graph object, as the container div (id "divGraph") has no context menu when right-clicked, per `mxEvent.disableContextMenu(container)`. And when I click and drag on the empty div, I can see a new div, `mxRubberband`, appear and alter its left/top/width/height styles in realtime as I drag the cursor around.

When inspected, the container div looks like this in the DOM:

```
<div class="graph-container" id="divGraph" style="width: 100%; position: relative; touch-action: none;">
  <svg style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; min-width: 1px; min-height: 1px;">
    <g>
      <g></g>
      <g></g>
      <g></g>
      <g></g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Changing the XML string that is parsed by mxUtils never seems to change the actual graph that is rendered in the React component; it always appears to have 4 empty `<g>` elements regardless of what XMLString I pass into `mxUtils.parseXml()`.

I've tried some different approaches, such as the ones detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527357/mxgraph-create-graph-with-xml), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54835679/initialize-mxgraph-with-default-xml-model), and the documentation examples [here](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/io/mxCodec-js.html), but to no avail. No errors appear in the console when using this component, so I'm not entirely sure where the issue is occurring.

It may be worth noting that I can successfully construct and render a graph when manually inserting vertices and edges via the `graph.insertVertex` and `graph.insertEdge` methods, like so:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import * as mxgraph from 'mxgraph';

const { mxClient, mxGraph, mxRubberband, mxUtils, mxEvent, mxKeyHandler } = mxgraph();

class DisplayGraph extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.LoadGraph = this.LoadGraph.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.LoadGraph();
  }

  LoadGraph() {
    var container = document.getElementById("divGraph");

    // Checks if the browser is supported
    if (!mxClient.isBrowserSupported()) {
      // Displays an error message if the browser is not supported.
      mxUtils.error("Browser is not supported!", 200, false);
    } else {
      // Disables the built-in context menu
      mxEvent.disableContextMenu(container);

      // Creates the graph inside the given container
      var graph = new mxGraph(container);

      // Enables rubberband selection
      new mxRubberband(graph);

      // Gets the default parent for inserting new cells. This is normally the first
      // child of the root (ie. layer 0).
      var parent = graph.getDefaultParent();

      // Enables tooltips, new connections and panning
      graph.setPanning(true);
      graph.setTooltips(true);
      graph.setConnectable(true);
      graph.setEnabled(true);
      graph.setEdgeLabelsMovable(false);
      graph.setVertexLabelsMovable(false);
      graph.setGridEnabled(true);
      graph.setAllowDanglingEdges(false);

      graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
      try {
        //mxGraph component
        var doc = mxUtils.createXmlDocument();
        var node = doc.createElement("Node");
        node.setAttribute("ComponentID", "[P01]");

        var vx = graph.insertVertex(
          parent,
          null,
          node,
          240,
          40,
          150,
          30,
          "shape=ellipse;fillColor=yellow"
        );

        var v1 = graph.insertVertex(
          parent,
          null,
          "shape1",
          20,
          120,
          80,
          30,
          "rounded=1;strokeColor=red;fillColor=orange"
        );
        var v2 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "shape2", 300, 120, 80, 30);
        var v3 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "shape3", 620, 180, 80, 30);
        var e1 = graph.insertEdge(
          parent,
          null,
          "",
          v1,
          v2,
          "strokeWidth=2;endArrow=block;endSize=2;endFill=1;strokeColor=blue;rounded=1;"
        );
        var e2 = graph.insertEdge(parent, null, "Edge 2", v2, v3);
        var e3 = graph.insertEdge(parent, null, "Edge 3", v1, v3);

        //data
      } finally {
        // Updates the display
        graph.getModel().endUpdate();
      }

      // Enables rubberband (marquee) selection and a handler for basic keystrokes
      var rubberband = new mxRubberband(graph);
      var keyHandler = new mxKeyHandler(graph);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="graph-container" ref="divGraph" id="divGraph"></div>
    );
  }
}

export default DisplayGraph;
```

So the module appears to be functioning, but I can't figure out why the XML String I'm passing into `mxUtils.parseXml()` isn't being properly parsed/rendered.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tried your the code posted above the decoding of xml and applying to graph model. For me, i could get a the shapes rendered on the UI. May be check your css if the container has enough width and hieight and it s not hiidden.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for trying out the code. I checked the graph-container div and its children and they appear to have visible height and width; just nothing inside them. 

I created a fresh React app (via create-react-app) and used the above DisplayGraph component to make sure the issue isn't due to any other modules in my main project. Unfortunately the component still failed to render the graph even though it was a clean React app. 

Can you tell me more about the environment that you ran the code in? Did you create a React app via create-react-app? What browser did you run it in?

Comment: Checkout this [codepen](https://codepen.io/marudhupandiyang/pen/MMeOKg)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I see in the CodePen that the mxGraph libraries are being imported via <script> tags in the HTML rather than with an import statement in the React component. Changing that appears to have gotten the graph to render for me, but I'm not entirely sure why the NPM module doesn't seem to work when imported directly into the React component.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is basically because the library you are using is in version 1.0.1 [mxgraph-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mxgraph-js), this library is very basic with the other features that the latest versions 4.0.6 [mxgraph](https://unpkg.com/mxgraph@4.0.6/javascript/mxClient.js) brings.
In order for your prototype to work, you must import a more current version of mxgraph, and you must do so using a  tag.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Graph extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.containerId = "divGraph";
    this.LoadGraph = this.LoadGraph.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
   var that= this;


   const script = document.createElement("script");    
   // script.src = "https://unpkg.com/mxgraph@3.9.8/javascript/mxClient.js";
   script.src = "https://unpkg.com/mxgraph@4.0.6/javascript/mxClient.js";
   script.async = true;    
   document.body.appendChild(script);


    setTimeout(() => {
      if(that.refs && this.refs.divGraph){
        console.log(20,mxClient);
        that.LoadGraph();
      };
    },1000)
  }

  LoadGraph() {

    var container = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.divGraph);
    var zoomPanel = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.divZoom);
    var xmlString='<mxGraphModel dx="492" dy="658" grid="1" gridSize="10" guides="1" tooltips="1" connect="1" arrows="1" fold="1" page="1" pageScale="1" pageWidth="827" pageHeight="1169">  <root>    <mxCell id="0" />    <mxCell id="1" parent="0" />    <mxCell id="2" value="" style="rounded=0;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;" parent="1" vertex="1">      <mxGeometry x="20" y="20" width="120" height="60" as="geometry" />    </mxCell>    <mxCell id="3" value="" style="whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;aspect=fixed;"parent="1" vertex="1">      <mxGeometry x="20" y="100" width="80" height="80" as="geometry" />    </mxCell>    <mxCell id="4" value="" style="ellipse;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;aspect=fixed;" parent="1" vertex="1">      <mxGeometry x="20" y="200" width="80" height="80" as="geometry" />    </mxCell>    <mxCell id="5" value="" style="triangle;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;" parent="1" vertex="1">      <mxGeometry x="20" y="300" width="60" height="80"as="geometry" />    </mxCell>    <mxCell id="6" value="" style="shape=hexagon;perimeter=hexagonPerimeter2;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;" parent="1" vertex="1">      <mxGeometry x="20" y="400" width="120" height="80" as="geometry" />    </mxCell>  </root></mxGraphModel>';

    if (!mxClient.isBrowserSupported()) {
      mxUtils.error("Browser is not supported!", 200, false);
    } else {
      this.container = document.getElementById(this.containerId);
      this.model = new mxGraphModel();
      var graph = new mxGraph(this.container, this.model);
      const parent = graph.getDefaultParent();

      this.model.beginUpdate();
            try
            {
        let xmlString = '<mxGraphModel dx="116" dy="608" grid="1" gridSize="10" guides="1" tooltips="1" connect="1" arrows="1" fold="1" page="1" pageScale="1" pageWidth="850" pageHeight="1100"><root><mxCell id="0"/><mxCell id="1" parent="0"/><mxCell id="2" value="Template" style="rounded=1;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;strokeColor=#00ACC1;strokeWidth=5;glass=0;comic=0;gradientColor=#b2ebf2;fillColor=#e0f7fa;fontSize=16;fontColor=#000000;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="210" y="120" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="3" value="Sub-Process" style="shape=process;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;backgroundOutline=1;strokeColor=#ffb74d;strokeWidth=4;perimeterSpacing=0;fontSize=16;gradientColor=#fff3e0;fillColor=#FFFFFF;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="210" y="260" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="4" value="End" style="ellipse;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;aspect=fixed;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fillColor=#ffebee;strokeColor=#f44336;strokeWidth=4;gradientColor=#ffcdd2;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="240" y="400" width="80" height="80" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="5" value="Process" style="shape=process;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;backgroundOutline=1;strokeColor=#ff9800;strokeWidth=4;perimeterSpacing=0;fontSize=16;gradientColor=#ffe0b2;fillColor=#fff3e0;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="240" y="500" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="6" value="Start" style="ellipse;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;aspect=fixed;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fillColor=#e8f5e9;strokeColor=#4caf50;strokeWidth=4;gradientColor=#c8e6c9;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="270" y="640" width="80" height="80" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="7" value="Start" style="ellipse;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;aspect=fixed;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fillColor=#e8f5e9;strokeColor=#4caf50;strokeWidth=4;gradientColor=#c8e6c9;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="270" y="740" width="80" height="80" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="8" value="Documentation" style="shape=document;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;boundedLbl=1;strokeWidth=4;strokeColor=#9C27B0;gradientColor=#E1BEE7;fillColor=#F3E5F5;fontSize=16;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="270" y="840" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="9" value="Sub-Process" style="shape=process;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;backgroundOutline=1;strokeColor=#ffb74d;strokeWidth=4;perimeterSpacing=0;fontSize=16;gradientColor=#fff3e0;fillColor=#FFFFFF;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="300" y="980" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="10" value="Template" style="rounded=1;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;strokeColor=#00ACC1;strokeWidth=5;glass=0;comic=0;gradientColor=#b2ebf2;fillColor=#e0f7fa;fontSize=16;fontColor=#000000;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="330" y="1120" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="11" value="Decision" style="rhombus;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;rounded=0;glass=0;comic=0;labelBackgroundColor=none;strokeColor=#333333;strokeWidth=4;fillColor=#eeeeee;gradientColor=#e5e5e5;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fontColor=#000000;align=center;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="360" y="1260" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="12" value="End" style="ellipse;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;aspect=fixed;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fillColor=#ffebee;strokeColor=#f44336;strokeWidth=4;gradientColor=#ffcdd2;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="390" y="1400" width="80" height="80" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="13" value="Process" style="shape=process;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;backgroundOutline=1;strokeColor=#ff9800;strokeWidth=4;perimeterSpacing=0;fontSize=16;gradientColor=#ffe0b2;fillColor=#fff3e0;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="390" y="1500" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="14" value="Documentation" style="shape=document;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;boundedLbl=1;strokeWidth=4;strokeColor=#9C27B0;gradientColor=#E1BEE7;fillColor=#F3E5F5;fontSize=16;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="420" y="1640" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="15" value="Phase" style="swimlane;html=1;horizontal=0;swimlaneLine=0;rounded=0;glass=0;comic=0;labelBackgroundColor=none;strokeColor=#000000;strokeWidth=4;fillColor=#26C6DA;gradientColor=#00ACC1;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fontColor=#FFFFFF;gradientDirection=east;spacing=0;spacingTop=-4;swimlaneFillColor=none;collapsible=0;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="450" y="1780" width="1020" height="200" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="16" value="Phase" style="swimlane;html=1;horizontal=0;swimlaneLine=0;rounded=0;glass=0;comic=0;labelBackgroundColor=none;strokeColor=#000000;strokeWidth=4;fillColor=#26C6DA;gradientColor=#00ACC1;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fontColor=#FFFFFF;gradientDirection=east;spacing=0;spacingTop=-4;swimlaneFillColor=none;collapsible=0;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="480" y="2000" width="1020" height="200" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="17" value="Phase" style="swimlane;html=1;horizontal=0;swimlaneLine=0;rounded=0;glass=0;comic=0;labelBackgroundColor=none;strokeColor=#000000;strokeWidth=4;fillColor=#26C6DA;gradientColor=#00ACC1;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fontColor=#FFFFFF;gradientDirection=east;spacing=0;spacingTop=-4;swimlaneFillColor=none;collapsible=0;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="510" y="2220" width="1020" height="200" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="18" value="Phase" style="swimlane;html=1;horizontal=0;swimlaneLine=0;rounded=0;glass=0;comic=0;labelBackgroundColor=none;strokeColor=#000000;strokeWidth=4;fillColor=#26C6DA;gradientColor=#00ACC1;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fontColor=#FFFFFF;gradientDirection=east;spacing=0;spacingTop=-4;swimlaneFillColor=none;collapsible=0;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="540" y="2440" width="1020" height="200" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="19" value="Process" style="shape=process;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;backgroundOutline=1;strokeColor=#ff9800;strokeWidth=4;perimeterSpacing=0;fontSize=16;gradientColor=#ffe0b2;fillColor=#fff3e0;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="570" y="2660" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="20" value="Start" style="ellipse;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;aspect=fixed;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fillColor=#e8f5e9;strokeColor=#4caf50;strokeWidth=4;gradientColor=#c8e6c9;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="600" y="2800" width="80" height="80" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="21" value="Process" style="shape=process;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;backgroundOutline=1;strokeColor=#ff9800;strokeWidth=4;perimeterSpacing=0;fontSize=16;gradientColor=#ffe0b2;fillColor=#fff3e0;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="600" y="2900" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="22" value="Action" style="rounded=1;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;glass=0;comic=0;labelBackgroundColor=none;strokeColor=#e91e63;strokeWidth=4;fillColor=#fce4ec;gradientColor=#f8bbd0;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fontColor=#000000;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="630" y="3040" width="280" height="40" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="23" value="Process" style="shape=process;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;backgroundOutline=1;strokeColor=#ff9800;strokeWidth=4;perimeterSpacing=0;fontSize=16;gradientColor=#ffe0b2;fillColor=#fff3e0;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="660" y="3100" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="24" value="Sub-Process" style="shape=process;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;backgroundOutline=1;strokeColor=#ffb74d;strokeWidth=4;perimeterSpacing=0;fontSize=16;gradientColor=#fff3e0;fillColor=#FFFFFF;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="690" y="3240" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="25" value="End" style="ellipse;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;aspect=fixed;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fillColor=#ffebee;strokeColor=#f44336;strokeWidth=4;gradientColor=#ffcdd2;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="720" y="3380" width="80" height="80" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="26" value="Decision" style="rhombus;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;rounded=0;glass=0;comic=0;labelBackgroundColor=none;strokeColor=#333333;strokeWidth=4;fillColor=#eeeeee;gradientColor=#e5e5e5;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fontColor=#000000;align=center;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="720" y="3480" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="27" value="Template" style="rounded=1;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;strokeColor=#00ACC1;strokeWidth=5;glass=0;comic=0;gradientColor=#b2ebf2;fillColor=#e0f7fa;fontSize=16;fontColor=#000000;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="750" y="3620" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="28" value="Process" style="shape=process;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;backgroundOutline=1;strokeColor=#ff9800;strokeWidth=4;perimeterSpacing=0;fontSize=16;gradientColor=#ffe0b2;fillColor=#fff3e0;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="780" y="3760" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="29" value="Start" style="ellipse;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;aspect=fixed;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fillColor=#e8f5e9;strokeColor=#4caf50;strokeWidth=4;gradientColor=#c8e6c9;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="810" y="3900" width="80" height="80" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="30" value="Documentation" style="shape=document;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;boundedLbl=1;strokeWidth=4;strokeColor=#9C27B0;gradientColor=#E1BEE7;fillColor=#F3E5F5;fontSize=16;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="810" y="4000" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="31" value="Phase" style="swimlane;html=1;horizontal=0;swimlaneLine=0;rounded=0;glass=0;comic=0;labelBackgroundColor=none;strokeColor=#000000;strokeWidth=4;fillColor=#26C6DA;gradientColor=#00ACC1;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fontColor=#FFFFFF;gradientDirection=east;spacing=0;spacingTop=-4;swimlaneFillColor=none;collapsible=0;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="840" y="4140" width="1020" height="200" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="32" value="Action" style="rounded=1;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;glass=0;comic=0;labelBackgroundColor=none;strokeColor=#e91e63;strokeWidth=4;fillColor=#fce4ec;gradientColor=#f8bbd0;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fontColor=#000000;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="870" y="4360" width="280" height="40" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="33" value="Documentation" style="shape=document;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;boundedLbl=1;strokeWidth=4;strokeColor=#9C27B0;gradientColor=#E1BEE7;fillColor=#F3E5F5;fontSize=16;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="900" y="4420" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="34" value="Phase" style="swimlane;html=1;horizontal=0;swimlaneLine=0;rounded=0;glass=0;comic=0;labelBackgroundColor=none;strokeColor=#000000;strokeWidth=4;fillColor=#26C6DA;gradientColor=#00ACC1;fontFamily=Helvetica;fontSize=16;fontColor=#FFFFFF;gradientDirection=east;spacing=0;spacingTop=-4;swimlaneFillColor=none;collapsible=0;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="930" y="4560" width="1020" height="200" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="35" value="Process" style="shape=process;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;backgroundOutline=1;strokeColor=#ff9800;strokeWidth=4;perimeterSpacing=0;fontSize=16;gradientColor=#ffe0b2;fillColor=#fff3e0;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="960" y="4780" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="36" value="Sub-Process" style="shape=process;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;backgroundOutline=1;strokeColor=#ffb74d;strokeWidth=4;perimeterSpacing=0;fontSize=16;gradientColor=#fff3e0;fillColor=#FFFFFF;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="990" y="4920" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell><mxCell id="37" value="Process" style="shape=process;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;backgroundOutline=1;strokeColor=#ff9800;strokeWidth=4;perimeterSpacing=0;fontSize=16;gradientColor=#ffe0b2;fillColor=#fff3e0;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="1020" y="5060" width="200" height="120" as="geometry"/></mxCell></root></mxGraphModel>';

        var doc = mxUtils.parseXml(xmlString);
        var codec = new mxCodec(doc);
        codec.decode(doc.documentElement, graph.getModel());
            }
            finally
            {
                graph.model.endUpdate();
            }
    }
  }
  render() {
    return <div className="graph-container" ref="divGraph" id="divGraph" />;
  }
}

export default Graph;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let xml = '<mxGraphModel><root><mxCell id="0"/><mxCell id="1" parent="0"/>...';
xml = xml.replace(/(?<=style=")([^;"=]+)(?=[;"])/g, "shape=$1");
let xmlDocument = mxUtils.parseXml(xml);
let decoder = new mxCodec(xmlDocument);
let node = xmlDocument.documentElement;
window['mxGraphModel'] = mxGraphModel; // why? see: mxCodec.js:429 -> `ctor = window[node.nodeName];`, nodeName is mxGraphModel/mxGeometry/...
window['mxGeometry'] = mxGeometry; // why? see: above
window['mxPoint'] = mxPoint; // why? see: above
decoder.decode(node, self.graph.getModel());
```

[mxCodec.js:429](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZOY4.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I found a way to resolve this in my webpack project (vuejs) , maybe it's the same problem

because all the mx Object must in window dict

e.g. window['mxCell'] = mxCell

so I write this

```
const {mxCell .......} = mxgraph({
  mxImageBasePath: ..... })

// register all object 
window['mxClient'] = mxClient
window['mxGraph'] = mxGraph
window['mxUtils'] = mxUtils
window['mxEvent'] = mxEvent
window['mxVertexHandler'] = mxVertexHandler

window['mxConstraintHandler'] = mxConstraintHandler
window['mxConnectionHandler'] = mxConnectionHandler
window['mxEdgeHandler'] = mxEdgeHandler
window['mxCellHighlight'] = mxCellHighlight

window['mxEditor'] = mxEditor
window['mxGraphModel'] = mxGraphModel
window['mxKeyHandler'] = mxKeyHandler
window['mxStencilRegistry'] = mxStencilRegistry

window['mxConstants'] = mxConstants
window['mxGraphView'] = mxGraphView
window['mxCodec'] = mxCodec
window['mxToolbar'] = mxToolbar
window['mxRubberband'] = mxRubberband

window['mxShape'] = mxShape
window['mxImage'] = mxImage
window['mxConnectionConstraint'] = mxConnectionConstraint
window['mxPoint'] = mxPoint
window['mxDivResizer'] = mxDivResizer

window['mxGraphHandler'] = mxGraphHandler
window['mxPerimeter'] = mxPerimeter
window['mxPolyline'] = mxPolyline
window['mxCellState'] = mxCellState
window['mxOutline'] = mxOutline

window['mxCell'] = mxCell
window['mxGeometry'] = mxGeometry
window['mxGuide'] = mxGuide
window['mxDefaultKeyHandler'] = mxDefaultKeyHandler
window['mxDefaultToolbar'] = mxDefaultToolbar

window['mxXmlCanvas2D'] = mxXmlCanvas2D
window['mxImageExport'] = mxImageExport

// your code here
```